# SAMBA chown: invalid user:

Tags: samba, ldap, chown

I am trying to add users to a LDAP server using SAMBA.
This is my list of users and user 'tester' was created using `smbldap-useradd`

```
admin@server:/export/home$ sudo smbldap-userlist
uid  |username

   0 |root                 |
65534 |nobody               |
1000 |tester               |
```

But when I create a directory 'tester' in /export/home/ and try to `sudo chown tester tester` I get the following error:
`chown: invalid user: ‘tester’`

Can anyone give me a detailed solution, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: smb is not equal to your system. You have to create a systemuser with the same uid first. Try on your system `getent passwd` if you don't see tester the system doesn't know it.

Comment: the user tester is not in the list from `getent passwd`
Is there a way to map system users to samba users other than creating a system user manually every time I create a new smb user?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a systemuser first and then only use `smbpasswd [username]` to set a password  for that user, so the user can use samba shares.

You have to set a seperate password for samba since it needs to be in a specific format.

However, see [samba docu](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html) for more information about that stuff.

If you have a ldap set up which you sync your samba already, you can make your system use that ldap aswell. E.g. see the [official ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication)